# Running times of priority queue ADT

Tags: c++

What are the running times of each of the functions of the (standard) priority
queue ADT if we implement it by adapting the STL priority queue?

Comment: Why don't you measure it yourself and come back and tell us? There's no true answer since there are so many variables - your computer and your compiler for starters. P.S. your title needs work.

Comment: This question needs a better title (at a minimum).

Comment: @DrewHall How about "gimme da codez?" :P

Comment: `pop()` is O(log(N)). `push()` is amortised O(log(N)), but O(N) if the underlying vector needs reallocation. Assuming the default `vector` as the container type.

Answer (score 2):

Complexity guarantees can be found in section 25.4.6 of the c++ standard. (Search for n3242.pdf; I'm sure you'll find one.) Alternatively, look at each heap operation listed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).